# Looking for a book with a girl protagonist travels through a portal guided by humanoid cats

Tags: story-identification, books

Here's all I can remember: The girl protagonist is guided by the catlike creatures through a portal to their world. I'm pretty sure the portals were always mirrors. In order to travel through the portal, one can't be wearing clothes, and the girl was embarrassed, even though the cats were always naked.

I'm also fairly certain that it was a children's or YA novel.